# Proving that $\mathrm {tr}(P)-\log\det(P) \geq n $ for positive denfinite $P$ with Kullback Leibler divergence

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

So, I was looking at the paper by [Andrzej CICHOCKI](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7146.pdf) and in the preliminary and notation part where they define some identities, the following identity is also given:

$$\mathrm {tr}(P)-\log \det(P) \geq n$$ where $P$ may be any positive definite matrix.

I was wondering how one would prove the above identity. I have read about the identity in the book [Graphical Models by Joe Whittaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470743662), but there it is only written that the identity is a corollary of a special case of Kullback Leibler divergence. So, how can we prove the above identity using the divergence?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of Kullback Leibler divergence.
But here is a proof of the inequality:
$$
\frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{n} \geq \left( x_1 + ... + x_n \right)^{1/n}
$$
or
$$
\frac{tr(P)}{n}  \geq \det(P)^{1/n}
$$
(using the expression of the trace and determinant in terms of eigenvalues)
$$
\log \left( \frac{tr(P)}{n}  \right) \geq \frac{1}{n} \log( \det(P) )
$$
Next use 
$$
x - 1 \geq \log( x ), \quad \, \forall x \geq 0,
$$
$$
\frac{1}{n} tr(P) - 1 \geq \frac{1}{n} \log( \det(P) )
\quad
\Rightarrow
tr(P) - n \geq \log( \det(P) )
$$